# Python Libraries not working in Terminal on Mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal, package, libraries

I was using virtualenv in terminal when my terminal crashed and all my libraries were working fine. All my packages/libraries are in  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages directory. I am using Python 3.8 I have tried export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages but this also does not work when I run my programs. I also get this error on certain programs: ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']-although Numpy is there in path I mentioned earlier. After the terminal crashed I can no longer create virtualenv's either, something is very wrong.

Comment: if you're using new python version you need to recreate the virtualenvs and re-install all the packages to work with the newer version

Comment: Can you give me an example? When I create a new virtualenv it says pandas etc already exist

Answer (score 0):

use python -m pip install [package] to install all packages.